# What is an EKEntityType?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was trying to make an EKCalender, when I found that I needed an `EKEntityType` for:

```
    collegeCalender = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:<#(EKEntityType)#> eventStore:<#(EKEventStore *)#>]
```

I searched for stuff online, but I couldn't find anything about it. Please Help!

Comment: Why don't you search the iOS reference documentation? You will find your answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EKEntityType` is nothing but  A value which specifies an entity type of event or reminder.
it is an enum define as below in `EKSource` Class

```
typedef enum {
   EKEntityTypeEvent,
   EKEntityTypeReminder
} EKEntityType;
```

choose `EKEntityTypeEvent` if you are dealing with an event, in case of Reminder use `EKEntityTypeReminder`.